# Git - How can I get a file's history added to another file... or something

Tags: git

Okay, so basically one of the dev's messed up. I'll try make it short so it's easier to understand.

We have file `/src/SomeFile.php` in `master`

Developer creates a new branch called `task-1`

Separate changes are made to `/src/SomeFile.php` in `master` and `task-1`

All normal up to here.

Developer decides to change the file structure in `master` and "moves" `/src/SomeFile.php` to `/src/newdir/SomeFile.php`. Except he doesn't use git to move the file, he creates a new file, copy and pastes the code from the old file into the new file and deletes the old file and does a commit.

Cue forward some more commits and we want to do a merge from `task-1` into `master` and find out that the commit history for `/src/newdir/SomeFile.php` doesn't contain the original commit history from when it was still `/src/SomeFile.php`

So now when we want to do a merge, it wants to completely overwrite the file in `master`, regardless of any commits that have happened since the branch, with the the file in `task-1` and I don't have anything meaningful to work off of for the merge conflict, because the it's showing the whole file to be different.

How do I fix this. I've rolled back the merge already. In a ideal world, I would be able to go back to the version before the file was moved, move the file with git, so that it retains it's commit history, then have git then reapply all the commits from the file move to right up to when the current master version (pre-merge), so that we can successfully merge. However, I know thats not possible.

So I'm wondering, if there is anyway I can tell git that this new file, is actually the old file, but in a different place, so it will reapply the file history to it, so that I can do a merge and get a meaningful diff when and if conflicts arise.

Sorry if it's not clear, I've tried my best to explain it.

**EDIT**

So playing around on github, if I look at the "new" file `/src/newdir/SomeFile.php` and look at it's history, it only shows the commit history from when the file was "moved" (copy/paste into new file, delete old file). However, if I look at "blame", it gives me a full commit history, even from the original file. Why is it this way only in blame and how do I get it to be in both?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using git 1.7.4+, you could try playing with the "rename-threshold" parameter (in %) during the merge in order to get git to consider the files rename candidates. For example:

```
git merge -X rename-threshold=25
```

This is the only way I can think of since git does not technically have the concept of first-class entity renaming. It just sort of detects file renames.

Comment: That didn't really do anything I'm afraid. I probably would have helped if the file had been "moved" in `task-1` and not master. I'm not sure. Either way, I did try it (went up to 75) and nothing really changed for me.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps lowering the threshold percentage figure as opposed to increasing it would work. Also, maybe this guy's script will help: https://gist.github.com/tvogel/894374

Comment: I think the problem isn't with the merge, it's with the fact that the rename isn't being recognized in master, so the commit history is not present. I sent the threshold=5. Still same results. Will look into that script and see what the story is.